# turtle keeps crashing and won't run on python 3.1.2 on mac os x 10.6.8

Tags: python, macos, turtle-graphics

I am brand new to coding. The book I'm learning from said to type:

```
import turtle
```

And then to type:

```
t = turtle.pen()
```

That last command brought up an empty window titled:

> Python Turtle Graphics.

This window is staying in the background and I get the spinning pinwheel.  The book said if this happened to try and use the Python console instead of the shell.  Tried bringing that up but couldn't.  Book said:

> open Terminal and enter python.

This did nothing.  Does anyone know how I can get turtle working?

Answer (score 0):

> t = turtle.pen()

This is a common error starting out with turtle -- either an error reading the code in the book or an error when the book was typeset (or simply a bad choice of font!)  What is really needed at this point in the code is:

```
t = turtle.Pen()
```

The `pen()` and `Pen()` methods are completely different.  Since `Pen()` is a synonym for `Turtle()`, I instead suggest:

```
t = turtle.Turtle()
```

to avoid the confusion.